# Error when adding child component routes in Angular 2 app.routing.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have app with Angular 2 as front end and node as the backend.

I was trying to add two URLS /products and /products/:id to my app.routing.ts as:

```
{
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    children: [
        { path: ':id',
          component: ProductDetailsComponent,
          canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can access:  http://localhost:3000/products properly

However, accessing http://localhost:3000/products/1 does not work and it takes me back to the http://localhost:3000/products page with the following error in the developer console:

```
"VM3964:55 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'ProductDetailsComponent'
```

What could be the issue here? Am I making a mistake in the way I am adding the paths in app.routing.ts?

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a child route (under `products` and therefore under `ProductsComponent`) then the `ProductsComponent` template needs to have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.  This tells Angular where to put the content of the `ProductDetailsComponent` template within the `ProductsComponent` template.

If, however, you do not want the product details template to be inside of the products template, then you should NOT list the `products/:id` route as a child route, but instead as a sibling:

```
{ 
  path: 'products', 
  component: ProductsComponent,
},
{ 
  path: 'products/:id', 
  component: ProductDetailsComponent
  canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] 
}
```

Comment: Jason, Can you provide some code snippet that would help understand better?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the example from my Pluralsight courses. Are you having trouble following along with one of the courses' examples?

You can find the code for my "Angular Routing" course (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing) here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

The APM-Final folder has the completed code for the application.